# Do SubmitEvents made by a 'submit' event contain the form values?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML form with multiple inputs and a submit button. I created an eventlistener on the form that listens for 'submit' events. This passes a SubmitEvent into the callback function.

What I'm wondering, is there a getter or quick object property that can take in the input name (AKA input[name="XYZ"] and return what the input's value was at the time of submission?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No.

The `target` property of the event will reference the `form` element. From that you can access the form controls (via `querySelector`, `elements` or any other DOM method).

That will give you the values at the current time, not at the time the event fired.

If you want that, you'll need to copy the values before they change.

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const data = new FormData(e.target);
  console.log([...data.entries()]);
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="one" value="1">
  <input name="two" value="2">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. An easy way to get those values in JS. Thanks a lot! I'm surprised I wasn't able to find something quite as useful in the documentation I found online

Comment: Sorry, I need to up my reading comprehension. So, the method you posted essentially copies the values at the time the event was called into a new object 'data' right? so if somehow the values were changed after the submit button was pushed, it would copy the new values? If that's true, it's slightly disappointing that the form specific submit even doesn't carry the input values. Still Thanks!

Comment: `Object.fromEntries(data.entries())` and you're golden

Comment: If someone needs this in React/TypeScript: `FormData` is not an option; use `e.currentTarget.elements`, it returns each item enumerated twice, by index number and HTML id. To get each item only once you can use `Array.from()`.

Comment: @Leo — I've used `FormData` with React and TypeScript, its fine.

Comment: @Quentin, at least from inside a form's `onSubmit` event handler with this shape `function onSubmitEventHandler(event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>): void` it seems not to be possible. Can you drop some link/snippet? It will help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to the value of an input field named "XYZ" you could access it like this when the submit event is fired.

```js
document.querySelector('[name="XYZ"]').value
```

Comment: Thank you. It's unfortunate that the values aren't stored in an object, so it looks like the SubmitEvent is just another event in that it calls a function.

Comment: Post more of the code as an example if you would like a more specific answer.